# In tflearn how can I add bias at start for mnist based model

Tags: mnist, tflearn

I'm using mnist data to build a model to read scores where I know that they will cluster around 5.  How can I add a bias to take account of this?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `bias_init` parameter in a layer. E.g. here: http://tflearn.org/layers/core/#fully-connected